# Magento Ecommerce - How to call and display a product's details into a CMS page?

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I would like to be able to insert and display a product the same way it is displayed in the product page, but into a CMS page (with attributes, prices, order button, etc...)

I've succeeded in creating a single page by inserting copied parts of the source code of a product page but this is quite a lenghty and time consuming process considering that I'm planning to have quite a few pages done.

Therefore I would like to be able to call the product details into a CMS page.

I thought I could use the view.phtml and insert it into the desired CMS page but I couldn't figure out how to define the product_id either...

Thank you all in advance for your comments

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, CMS Macro like this:

`{{block type="catalog/product" template="catalog/product/line-item.phtml" sku_id="CI 101"}}`

Referencing template catalog/product/line-item.phtml:

```
<?php //Template_Name/catalog/product/line-item.phtml
      //{{block type="catalog/product" template="catalog/product/line-item.phtml" sku_id="CI 100"}}
      //Feed template SKU for product listing 
?>

<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$this->getData('sku_id')); ?>

<?php /* get special freight messages from custom variables */
    $freightfree = Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('free_freight_text')->getValue('plain');
    $hazmat = Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('hazmat_text')->getValue('plain');
    $ormd = Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('ormd_text')->getValue('plain');
?>

<!-- <div class="single-product"> -->
<div class="listing-type-list catalog-listing">
<div class="listing-item last">
    <?php $specialshipping = $_product->getAttributeText('special_shipping_group') ?>

        <?php // Product Image ?>
        <div class="product-image">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getSmallImageLabel()) ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135, 135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
            </a>
        </div>

        <?php // Product description ?id= echo $_product->getId();?>
        <div class="product-shop">
            <h2><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName())?></a></h5>
            <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
            <?php if(!$_product->getNotforsale()): ?>
                <?php if(!$_product->getReplace_add_button()): ?>
                    <?php if($_product->isGrouped()): ?>
                        <button class="form-button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><?php echo $this->__('View Selection') ?></span></button>
                    <?php elseif($_product->getHasOptions()): ?>
                        <button class="form-button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><?php echo $this->__('View Options') ?></span></button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <button class="form-button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <button class="form-button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>')"><span><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('replace_add_button') ?></span></button>                    
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php  /* display special freight messages from custom variables */ ?>
            <?php if($specialshipping == "Free Ground" || $specialshipping == "Free Gnd ORMD"): ?>
                <?php echo '<span class="regular-price"><span class="freightfree">' . $freightfree . '</span></span>' ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($specialshipping == "ORM-D"): ?>
                <?php echo '<span class="freightfree">' . $ormd . '</span>' ?>
            <?php elseif($specialshipping == "Free Gnd ORMD"): ?>
                <?php echo '<br><span class="freightfree">' . $ormd . '</span>' ?>
            <?php elseif($specialshipping == "HazMat"): ?>
                <?php echo '<span class="freightfree">' . $hazmat . '</span>' ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="description">
                <?php echo nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()) ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><small><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></small></a>
            </div>
            <p class="add-to">
                Brand Name: <?php echo $_product->getBrand() ?>
            </p>
        </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Be aware this is pulling in several custom attributes and variables you probably won't find on your system. The most important is the CMS Macro

`{{block type="catalog/product" template="catalog/product/line-item.phtml" sku_id="CI 101"}}`

and this line:

`<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$this->getData('sku_id')); ?>`

Use Macro as many times on the CMS page as you want.

Comment: Check your CMS pages using this regularly. If someone gets cute and deletes an SKU from your catalog without paying attention, it will throw a nonexistent object error. I need to add a test for that when I get time.

Comment: Fantastic... this did the job nicely... thanks a lot for that ;-)

Comment: Hi Fiasco Labs... If I wanted to do the same thing from a category description, how would I go about that? When I paste the same code (which works perfectly from a CMS page) doesn't work in/from a category description.
I tried with <script><div> ... </div></script> but to no avail
Please advise. Thx a lot again ;-)

Comment: I don't think the Category Description text area is passed through the macro interpreter used in CMS. Have you tried making a CMS block with the included code and use it in the "Display Settings" tab? Set "Display Mode" dropdown to show Static Block or Static Block and Product and then set "CMS Block" dropdown to use your CMS block.